# Click anchor link and keep page position / prevent page-jump to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen variants of this question asked on SO previously, but these all concern anchors that point nowhere (i.e., href="#") or are placeholders for some javascript. My situation is different in that my anchors DO point somewhere, e.g.,

```
<a href="#one"><img src="../images/details_thumb.jpg">
```

More specifically, they interact with a css gallery that advances the main image each time a thumbnail or the image itself is clicked, as below. What I would like to do is have this occur without the default 'target = top' behaviour of href.

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul id="gallery-interior">

<li id="one"><img src="../images/details.jpg" usemap="#gallerymap" ><map name="gallerymap">
<area shape="circ" coords="429,157,30" href="#two"></map></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class=' thumbs'>
<a href="#one"><img src="../images/details.jpg">
</div>
```

Whilst I have seen many javascript solutions to this, they all deactivate the link functionality in so doing.

I should say that while I'm happy to have a js / jquery solution, I am not looking to change my html / css navigation for javascript / jquery -- I wish navigation to remain operative for those who use Noscript.

Can anyone help -- with a demonstrably working solution?

N.B. I've tried 'scroll-sneak' (http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/) but it has zero documentation and is notoriously difficult to get working.

UPDATED the js that captures the url hash to switch thumbnail opacity (to match gallery navigation) can be seen working, but for the scroll-sneak element, at http://www.ddsol.net/soDavePage/page/testFixed.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scroll Sneak**

Here's a method that implements scroll sneak. There's a slight flickering in Firefox 3 due to the small delay in the browser firing the scroll event, but it works as requested.

```
var sneaky = new ScrollSneak("gallery", false);
var capture = true;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlHash = window.location.hash;

    $(".thumbs a").on("click", function(e) {
        sneaky.sneak();
        capture = true;
        dimThumbs($(this).attr("href"));
    });

    $("#gallery-interior area").on("click", function(e) {
        sneaky.sneak();
        capture = true;
        dimThumbs($(this).attr("href"));
    });

    if(urlHash) {
        dimThumbs(urlHash);
    } else {
        $(".thumbs a:first-child img").addClass("dimmed"); // Dim first thumbnail
    }

    capture = false;

});

window.onscroll = function () {
    if (capture) sneaky.scroll(), capture = false;
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    sneaky.sneak();
};

function dimThumbs(active) {
    $(".thumbs a img").removeClass("dimmed");
    $(".thumbs a[href='" + active + "'] img").addClass("dimmed");
}
```

**Another Update**

It's become a mission now. This is a slight modification of the second version; I think that considering the only problem was that the image wasn't showing, this will likely address that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlHash = window.location.hash;

    if(urlHash) {
        setTimeout(function() { $("body").scrollTop(0) }, 1); // Scroll to top.
        changeImage(urlHash);
    } else {
        $(".thumbs a:first-child img").addClass("dimmed"); // Dim first thumbnail
    }

    $(".thumbs a").on("click", function(e) {
        changeImage($(this).attr("href"), e);
    });

    $("#gallery-interior area").on("click", function(e) {   
        changeImage($(this).attr("href"), e);
    });

});

function changeImage(active, e) {
    var e = window.event || e;
    preventNav(active, e);
    $(".thumbs a img").removeClass("dimmed");
    $(".thumbs a[href='" + active + "'] img").addClass("dimmed");
    $("#gallery-interior li").hide(0, function(){
        $("#gallery-interior " + active).show();
    });
}

function preventNav(hash, e) {
    if (e) {
        if (typeof e.preventDefault != 'undefined') {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    var node = $(hash);
    node.attr("id", "");
    document.location.hash = hash;
    node.attr("id", hash.replace("#", ""));
}
```

**Second Update**

This should operate exactly as you wanted, just replace the script you currently have. It flips between the gallery images, dims the correct thumbnail, prevents page navigation and stops the page from jumping to the element while still changing the document hash. Here's a fiddle to demo http://jsfiddle.net/C2B2M/; it's missing the images, I didn't want to hot-link to your site.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlHash = window.location.hash;

    if(urlHash) {
        setTimeout(function() { $("body").scrollTop(0) }, 1); // Scroll to top.
        changeImage(urlHash);
    } else {
        $(".thumbs a:first-child img").addClass("dimmed"); // Dim first thumbnail
    }

    $(".thumbs a").on("click", function(e) {
        changeImage($(this).attr("href"), e);
    });

    $("#gallery-interior area").on("click", function(e) {   
        changeImage($(this).attr("href"), e);
    });

});

function changeImage(active, e) {
    preventNav(active, e);
    $(".thumbs a img").removeClass('dimmed'); // Wipe out all dims
    $(".thumbs a[href='" + active + "'] img").addClass("dimmed"); // Dim the current thumbnail
    $("#gallery-interior li").hide(); // Hide all gallery images
    $("#gallery-interior " + active).show(); // Show current image
}

function preventNav(hash, e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    var node = $(hash);
    node.attr("id", "");
    document.location.hash = hash;
    node.attr("id", hash.replace("#", ""));
}
```

**Update**

Here's another attempt and also a fiddle for you to try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/EPsLV/4/

```
$(function () {
    $("a").on("click", function(e){
        var hash = $(this).attr("href");
        if (hash.match(/^#\w+/g)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var node = $(hash);
            node.attr("id", "");
            document.location.hash = hash;
            node.attr("id", hash.replace("#", ""));
        }
    });
});
```

This snippet captures any hash links and removes the id of the destination element long enough to change the page hash and then resumes the event propagation. I think that may be what your gallery is using to change the images, this script shouldn't stop the event itself from bubbling.

**Previous**

This should work for you

`$("div.thumbs a").on("click", function(e){
if ($(this).attr("href").match(/^#/))
e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work This is why I asked for a "...a demonstrably working solution", e.g., in a fiddle, as I have asked this question in two previous instances and none of the suggestions work.

Comment: Do the links for the gallery stop working entirely when this is used? This jQuery specifically targets only the gallery nav links.

Comment: The links continue to work, but the script seemingly has no affect -- the default scroll to top behaviour is unaffected. JQuery installed.

Comment: There, I think that should do exactly what you're needing. It's tested and appears to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply aecend; as your fiddle script works but still doesn't in my code, I've updated the question, posting a link to the live gallery showing the other js code (courtesy of SO member 'Spanka') that links the gallery to the thumbs. I don't know if interaction between the two is the problem, but whichever script runs first the result is the same.

Comment: Impressive, and exactly what I want -- but it has a problem. Looking at your code, I wondered about the necessity for the 'Hide/Show all gallery images' sub-elements of the function, as this aspect of functionality is controlled by the css. In this vein, the problem is that the main gallery image disappears on page refresh -- not in all browsers certainly, but the code fails in FF3 where the current js doesn't. I know FF3 is a very old browser, but this and IE6 are my baseline for operability and I need js that degrades gracefully when unsupported not code that breaks basic page functionality.

Comment: Can this show/hide functionality be excised from your solution as it's not clear why it's necessary (i.e., css-based) and I need code that is safe cross-browser?

best,
D

Comment: You say that your code "...flips between the gallery images", and this appears to be what the function below does:

function changeImage(active, e) {
    preventNav(active, e);
    ...
    $("#gallery-interior li").hide(); // Hide all gallery images
    $("#gallery-interior " + active).show(); // Show current image
}

Why was this aspect implemented, as it is very much not what was wanted ("...I am not looking to change my html / css navigation for javascript / jquery -- I wish navigation to remain operative for those who use Noscript")?

Comment: This does not remove the HTML/CSS navigation. In the case that a user is not using JavaScript, it operates exactly as it did before. The only way to prevent the page jumping on a link click is by using JavaScript. The script I provided switches the images and title in the gallery without changing pages, but it still updates the document hash. If the user refreshes the page, the gallery returns to the image last viewed by reading the document hash. No links other than ones related to the gallery are affected at all. I read the comments in your code and implemented fixes for each of the problems

Comment: Try the JavaScript out on the test page that you posted. If it still doesn't operate as you've asked, I'd be glad to make another attempt with further information as to what is missing.

Comment: One more thing, I made no changes at all to the way the gallery operates when no script is present; the only changes to HTML I made were fixes to tags that hadn't been closed properly. This only extends functionality when the script is being used.

Comment: I just noticed you're previous comments, not sure how I missed them. Give me a minute, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Sorry about that, I believe the problem is fixed now.

Comment: Afraid not aecend; whilst the blank image in FF3 is rectified, it is at the expense of broken functionality in the rest of the js -- the page jump has returned and the opacity class is no longer functional, i.e., the thumbs no longer change state in tandem with the navigation... This is the case in all three browsers tried (IE, FF, QupZ)

Comment: Another possibility is applying the scroll-sneak code (http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/), perhaps; it is functional on a similar unordered list on the developer's demo site.

Comment: Would you mind describing in a comment exactly what is happening when you click a thumbnail and refresh the page? From what you're saying, it sounds like the page is continuing to navigate despite the e.preventDefault

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with console-logging, and my brief inquiries just now show that it's non-trivial for the non-js adept. Clicking a thumb activates the opacity and jumps the page to the top. Clicking a nav link doesn't activate the thumb opacity and also jumps the page to the top. Incidentally, the "problems" identified in my js-code comments are those that the code addresses -- that code works faultlessly across browsers and only wants for the scroll-sneak code at the end to be successfully implemeted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your efforts aecend -- unfortunately, this doesn't change anything from the previous iteration: the page-jump is still there and the gallery-thumb opacity link remains broken. You say that "...this isn't a scrolling issue", but your 'Second Update' worked fine but for losing the gallery images. Still, unless you'd like to take a shot at making the scroll-sneak function at the end of my js work, I guess we'd better leave it there. Thanks again.

Comment: The issue was the return false I added at the end of the changeImage function. It was never setting the click handlers on the images. I also moved the code for showing the correct image into the hide function's callback. That should prevent the show from being called while the hide is still happening.

Comment: And what a mission -- now working. Thank you for your determination aecend! If you would would like to apply this rather formidable js skill-set to the 'scroll sneak' problem in a simpler code scenario, please see my other open and unanswered question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723615/making-scroll-sneak-work. cheers!

Comment: There's the scroll sneak method. I finally just downloaded FF3 and ensured that it was working properly. Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks aecend, please drop your solution into the SO page I linked to to be accepted as the answer for that question. Whilst it is a bit jerky, as you say (where the scroll-sneak demo is not), the 'scope' of your solution is applied to every element on the page where scroll-sneak is able to be applied as an event handler to specific tags and elements. Also, your js has functions for elements (thumbs, gallery-interior) that don't appear on these other pages, and what I was after was a sneak implementation that could be applied to the TH links (see specific question). In any event, I thank you!