# Making 'scroll-sneak' work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make the javascript code 'scroll-sneak' (http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/) work for a few weeks now. This code stops the 'page jump' (to the top) when an anchor link is clicked, and does so without disabling the functionality of that link. I'd like to have the page not move back to the top when a navigation link in a table row below is clicked. It works on the developer's demo page, but is none too well documented. Any takers for tacking this?

```
<tr id="tabs">

<th><a href="index.htm">Information</a></th>

<th><a href="plan.htm">Research</a></th>

<th><a href="councils.htm">Sources</a></th>

<th><a href="university.htm">Institution</a></th>

<th><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></th>

</tr>

<script>
(function() {
var sneaky = new ScrollSneak(location.hostname), tabs = 
document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName('th'), i = 0, len = tabs.length;
for (; i < len; i++) {
tabs[i].onclick = sneaky.sneak;
}
    document.getElementById('next').onclick = sneaky.sneak; 
})();
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

In terms of my original question (and given the various problems and bugs described in the Comments below, the accepted answer proving too unpredictable in behaviour), I managed to figure out a simple solution, as below, that works in IE6, FF3, QZ6 and Webkit 537.21.

```
(function() {
var sneaky = new ScrollSneak(location.hostname);
document.getElementById('tabs').onclick = sneaky.sneak;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One more edit:**

If the last image is still giving you trouble, you can make this change and see if it helps:

Replace this:

```
$(active).show();
$(active).siblings().hide();
```

With this:

```
$("#gallery-interior li").hide(0, function(){
        $("#gallery-interior " + active).show();
});
```

**Previous**

Here, I combined the script from the other answer and the scroll-sneak for the tabs. I tested both in FF3 and verified that they work properly, this is the complete JavaScript:

```
var sneaky = new ScrollSneak("scrolltrack");

$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlHash = window.location.hash;

    if(urlHash) {
        $(".thumbs a[href='" + urlHash + "'] img").addClass("dimmed");
    } else {
        $(".thumbs a:first-child img").addClass("dimmed");
    }

    $("#tabs th a").on("click", function(e) {
        sneaky.sneak();
    });

    $(".thumbs a").on("click", function(e) {
        changeImage($(this).attr("href"), e);
    });

    $("#gallery-interior area").on("click", function(e) {   
        changeImage($(this).attr("href"), e);
    });

});

function changeImage(active, e) {
    var e = window.event || e;
    preventNav(active, e);
    $(".thumbs a img").removeClass("dimmed");
    $(".thumbs a[href='" + active + "'] img").addClass("dimmed");
    $(active).show();
    $(active).siblings().hide();
}

function preventNav(hash, e) {
    if (e) {
        if (typeof e.preventDefault != 'undefined') {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    var node = $(hash);
    node.attr("id", "");
    document.location.hash = hash;
    node.attr("id", hash.replace("#", ""));
}
```

**Previous**

Here you go, this script is adapted to the tabs. In the solution I posted for the gallery ([Click anchor link and keep page position / prevent page-jump to top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714369/click-anchor-link-and-keep-page-position-prevent-page-jump-to-top/)), the page jump happens because hash links don't actually reload the page and scrolling happens by default and has to be undone. This won't have the same jumping effect for normal links, but I left the ability to capture hash links as well in case you need it. It would be best if this were placed at the bottom of the HTML of your site, just before the closing body tag.

```
var sneaky = new ScrollSneak("tabs", false);
var capture = true;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlHash = window.location.hash;

    $("#tabs th a").on("click", function(e) {
        sneaky.sneak();
        capture = true;
    });

    capture = false;

});

window.onscroll = function () {
    if (capture) sneaky.scroll(), capture = false; // This part is only needed for hash links
};
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that you may need both this script and the other to be present on the same page. If you need me to make changes so you can combine them, that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks aecend; all in-place, but not working -- page jumps to the top on link-click. Hash-facility not needed and I have style classes that I apply to the tr and th, if that makes troubleshooting easier. I just saw your comment -- yes, that would be useful.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'd overlooked a simple mistake. All fixed now, and I removed the hash portion relative to the tabs.

Comment: Splendid, answer Accepted. Just one issue :) In IE6, the combined script above stops the gallery progressing to the last item in the List (#five), whether it's selected by gallery navigation or thumbnail. This behaviour disappears when the js is commented-out. What might be going on here?

Comment: Does the thumbnail dim? There are some broken HTML tags in the gallery HTML that you had in the other question. Here's a pen where I fixed them: http://codepen.io/aecend/pen/vEcqt. I never tried it with the broken code, but my guess is that IE is in quirks mode, and that can be unpredictable. MAP tags and P tags both need to be closed.

Comment: Nope, no thumbnail dimming, and broken tags fixed since then. I'll run my html through a validator now that the navigation is functional and will check the gallery in a later version of IE. Strange that commented-out js alleviates the nav problem though. Thanks again for all your help aecend -- inspiring stuff!

Comment: I added an update above. Try replacing the two lines in changeImage with the ones above and see if it works then.

Comment: I'm afraid that this update causes the gallery image to disappear in IE6, just as the earlier gallery js code did in FF3. My testing of the above combined code focused on the navigation scroll, but I've since found something amiss with the behaviour on page-refresh: the gallery jumps up and then down, but not to the original scroll-position and the gallery disappears again in FF3. Again, not sure what is going on here as you say you tested in this same browser :(

Comment: Thanks for your time aecend, but I think I'm going to leave it there. I've rolled-back my code to the original js that works everywhere I've tried. All I really asked for was implementation of scroll-sneak-type maintain scrolling with my working code, and asking me to swap all of my code for yours has resulted in endless bugs and unpredictable behaviour to the degree that the js often obstructs basic html and css navigation.